# youtube url for android videoview

Tags: android, video, youtube

I want to develop an app which downloads or plays a video from youtube in `VideoView`.
I've seen many resources like:

1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#Overview
2. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/
3. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/
4. [https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference/](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Finally the question is if i have the youtube **videoid** how can i stream it in **videoview**.
**I know to retrieve .3gp live streaming video but i want mp4 hd video to play in        videoview**

Comment: Is there any one who can just suggest the links pls...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May someone else may need this.

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AlertDetail.this, "", "Loading Video wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FJHYqE0RDg";
            videoUrl = getUrlVideoRTSP(url);
            Log.e("Video url for playing=========>>>>>", videoUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Login Soap Calling in Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(AlertDetail.this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();          
        mc.show();
    }

}

public static String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube)
{
    try
    {
        String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder =     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
        URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
        Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");///media:content
        String cursor = urlYoutube;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            if (node != null)
            {
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++)
                {
                    Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                    maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                }
                if (maps.containsKey("yt:format"))
                {
                    String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                    if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                    {
                        cursor = maps.get("url");
                    }
                    if (f.equals("1"))
                        return cursor;
                }
            }
        }
        return cursor;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
    }
    return urlYoutube;

}

protected static String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException
{
    String id = null;
    try
    {
        String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
        if (query != null)
        {
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            for (String row : param)
            {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v"))
                {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (url.contains("embed"))
            {
                id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
    }
    return id;
}
```